# Loading of view takes too long in XPages

Tags: xpages

I have 4 databases and they have more than 200.000 datas. A viewPanel which shows all datas of database does not load correcttly.  It turns out with an error after little bit waiting. If that view does not have lots of datas no error is given.
I could not find a solution for this situation :(

I added this line into Application Property but It did not solved my problem. 

xsp.domino.view.navigator=ByNoteId

Regards
Cumhur Ata

Comment: What error, exactly? How many documents in that particular view/database? Do they update frequently?

Comment: Well I might be crazy but I'm going to guess that if you posted that actual error message and maybe even the code for the viewPanel your chances for getting help will go up astronomically.

Comment: Are you using @Today/@Now in any of the view selections/column formula? If so, this has a bit impact on performance. However, as Frantisek and David mention, its hard for us to help without some more information from you....

Comment: The only think i can say is that Even if i do not use @Today() or @Now() formula If i have more documents Loading view will take too long

Comment: can it be from our server configuration or physical attributes? (CPU, RAM etc. )

Comment: @CumhurAta Your statement suggests that you actually DO use @_Today or @_Now (in your view selection formula that's without ()). A view panel usually shows 30 entries - how many are you trying to load? You can see the raw view performance using ...nsf/ViewName?ReadViewEntries

Comment: Every time you use @_Now, @_Today, @_Yesterday, @_Tomorrow in a view - a kitten must die. In my QA a database using those can't get deployed to a server - once you get rid of those (ALL of them on the entire server) performance takes a jump

Comment: xsp.domino.view.navigator=ByNoteId only minimises the amount of data held in the component tree about each row entry between requests. It is likely to have minimal impact on page load times.

Comment: @stwissel I can see all datas and some people also can see all datas, too.
The only time i can't manager this kind of situation when a user would like to see all datas in a view. I do not know what else i can say about my situation. :( 
I will be checking of all suggestion mentioned below/above. 
Thank you so much..

Comment: Pointers: SOME -> so you use reader fields? Previous answers suggest date/time use, so you have 2 of the biggies already

Comment: Yes I use 2 reader fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of performance "sins" you can commit on Domino. Unfortunately Domino is too forgiving and somehow still works even if you do them. The typical sins:

- Using @Yesterday, @Today, @Now, @Tomorrow ind a view selection formula or a sorted column in a view. I wrote [an article about your options](http://notessensei.com/blog/2012/11/managing-today-in-view-selection-formulas.html) to mitigate that
- Having code that does a view.refresh before opening a page
- Using reader fields and accessing a view that is not categorized by that reader field. Hits only users who can see only few documents. Check [this article](http://www.notessensei.com/blog/2009/02/reader-fields-again.html) for possible remedies
- Not having a fast temp location for view rebuilds. Typical errors are: not enough disk I/O or having your transaction log on the same channel as your databases. Make sure you have a [high performance server](http://www.notessensei.com/blog/2009/04/building-a-high-performance-domino-server.html)
- For Windows servers: not taking care of [disk fragmentation](http://www.notessensei.com/blog/2010/01/domino-and-disk-fragmentation.html) - includes links to performance trouble shooting
- Not using ODS51/52 and have compression for data and design active. Takes a [simple command](http://www.notessensei.com/blog/2006/01/fixing-a-notes-database.html) to fix it

That's off my head what you can check. Loading 200k documents into a panel in one go doesn't look like a good UX approach. Paginate it eventually

Comment: Pagination can also be via the xe:pagerAddRows control. I would agree with Stephan regarding this not being a good UX approach. I have never scrolled through 20,000 entries on the web on a single site. I would not accept having to do so. And I would severely challenge the veracity of any user who claims they would scroll through 20,000 entries.